# XAMPP (WAMP) server - disable accessing files outside of root directory

Tags: php, apache, xampp, windows-8.1, document-root

I'm using XAMPP on Windows 8.1.

I've this in apache config:

```
DocumentRoot "C:\Users\David\Dropbox\Programming\PHP"
<Directory "C:\Users\David\Dropbox\Programming\PHP">
```

VHosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName http://spedice
DocumentRoot "C:\Users\David\Dropbox\Programming\PHP\Projects_Kuba\Spedice\SczCMS\www"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName http://domaciucetnictvi
DocumentRoot "C:\Users\David\Dropbox\Programming\PHP\Projects_Kuba\DomaciUcetnictvi\www"
</VirtualHost>
```

But if I try accessing root directory - C or accessing some folder like C:\Program Files etc. It normally works. How can I disable going outside of this folder: C:\Users\David\Dropbox\Programming\PHP?

Fxp:

script.php

```
<?php
mkdir('../../../../../../folder');
?>
```

Placed in: C:\Users\David\Dropbox\Programming\PHP\Projects_Kuba\DomaciUcetnictvi\www

Called like: `http://domaciucetnictvi/script.php`

Thanks!

Comment: If you are actually accessing C:\Users\David\Dropbox\Programming\PHP in your address bar - and I fear you do - Apache doesn't do anything - you are just using your browser as an explorer. 

What you should do (and which magically makes your PHP code actually work) is visit http://localhost/

Comment: I've updated my question. Hope its understandable now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to modify the [open_basedir settings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) in your PHP config (just see [Runtime Configuration](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.php) for further information). This will prevent PHP from accessing directories outside of the definded basedir(s).

---EDIT---

To be a bit more conclusive. You can set open_basedir in your Apache configuration file, php.ini, or in a .htaccess file.

In php.ini, you can do this for example by adding:

```
open_basedir = "/path/to/first/folder:/path/to/second/folder"
```

In .htacces you can do it with:

```
php_flag open_basedir "/path/to/first/folder"
```

In your Apache config try:

```
<Directory /docroot1>
   php_admin_value open_basedir /path/to/first/folder
</Directory>

<Directory /docroot2>
   php_admin_value open_basedir /path/to/second/folder
</Directory>
```